# jQuery calculate $(document).height() too late?

Tags: jquery

Ok, so I'm doing this page: http://www.muzykakoncerty.pl/ . I must dynamic calculate few css attributes to get good effect. The problem is, that if i use $(document).height() then first time before refresh (every browser?!) elements using $(document).height() are bad-calculated. Check-out yourself. On main page issue is right-centered text "baw się ..." and on another pages is main photo on left side. Just try to refresh page, and u will see difference

any ideas what cause the problem?

EDIT:
OK! I know what is issue. Probably browser is loading and getting too late graphics and theirs size (width and height). 
New question is: How to check if graphics are loaded?

EDIT2:
Here is video thats showing the issue:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GCc_S7SdtI

Comment: looks good to me !! I don't see any changes after I refresh :(  I am using chrome 10 on win 7

Comment: I have to be honest, I'm not seeing/understanding exactly what the issue is. Everything looks ok to me

Comment: are you just trying to get traffic to your site :)

Comment: Post your code, where is it supposed to be?

Comment: try to use the latest browser. may be it can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.onload is not supposed to fire until the images are loaded. You could wait for that particular event. Note that $.ready is *not* window.onload; it happens before onload. I am not sure if you can bind the onload event with jQuery, but you probably can with the .bind method.

```
$(window).bind('load', function() {
     alert($(document).height());
});
```

Comment: interesting idea, i will check it out :)

Comment: or... i can just make preloader :D

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what the exact problem is but if you want to get css attribute of a specific object then you can use..`offset`

```
var ofset = $('#id').offset();
var hieght = ofset.top;
var left = ofset.left;
```

hoope this will help you...if i am guessing right.